# Using R to run Binary Regression Start to Finish

Tags: binary, compare, unique, regression

I'm really new at R, and I want to run a binary regression from a bunch of imported data. My goal is to determine if having a one-man (or woman) team has an impact on whether projects are completed on time. I'm trying to break down the process and I think I need to do the following:

1)I have a column of teams and a column of names. Some of the teams will only have 1 person on them, while others will have more than one. I want to compare the two columns to determine if a team only has 1 member, and create a binary column where value = TRUE = 1 = only 1 person on the team, and value = FALSE = 0 = more than one person on the team. This will output column "Solo_Team_Bin".

2) Compare two columns that each have dates listed in the form of MM/DD/YYY, and create a new binary column which shows if Date 1 <= Date 2 (i.e 'on-time') to determine if a project was completed on time.

I believe once I have the two binary columns I can then run a regression. Can anyone point me in the right direction for generating the binary column of whether a team is only 1 person, and whether the projects were completed before their predicted date? Any help would be appreciated.